# Why would I flag a question that most people certainly liked and upvoted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

**I may be wrong I am just asking for some clarification.**

As a part of Stack Overflow learning experience I have a question about a recent (highly liked) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277560/solid-principles-and-code-structure?noredirect=1#comment25049591_17277560) asked on Stack Overflow.

I think it's a good question and the answers are good too. Some people will definitely learn something new from reading it. Although, it's somehow (more or less) related to programming, it's not specifically asking to solve a 'code' problem.

In my understanding this is not the type of question we are expecting/tolerating on Stack Overflow, but all the upvotes and likes got me really confused. Is my judgement really that poor?

Comment: Looks to me like its a better fit for programmers.

Comment: That a question is upvoted and liked a lot does not necessarily mean it's good for the site, nor that there aren't any better sites for it. It merely means it's popular, which may happen for a number of reasons.

Comment: The question was just migrated to Programmers. I deleted the Meta discussion in the comments (and unfortunately also mistakenly deleted the one comment that wasn't about its topicality, sorry).

Comment: why is this a good question? won't a simple google search solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions that don't belong here should be closed no matter how many votes they have because

- If we make exceptions for interesting questions soon you can ask whatever you want.
- You can vote with only 15 rep. That can mean that many unexperienced SO-users vote for a question they like but is off-topic or has other issues.
- Others might take such questions as example and ask similar questions thinking that is fine.

Answer (score 3):

That a question has upvotes doesn't mean it's automatically immune from flagging.  If you feel that a question should be closed because it meets a particular criteria for closure then you should vote/flag accordingly.  The number of votes on the question is not relevant in that decision.

SO is not designed to answer every question anyone ever has.  It's not even designed to answer every *good* question anyone has.  There are lots of questions that are on topic, well researched, have the potential to be relevant and useful for many people, etc. but are still inappropriate for the site.  In this case, due to a significant amount of subjectivity as well as being excessively broad and open ended.  The SE system simply isn't built, from a technical standpoint, to support the discussions that inevitably ensue.  For that reason such questions are closed as they have historically shown to cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: i get what you are saying and i agree. It just makes me feel like a dic* when im about to flag a question with so many upvotes. I dont want to stand out of the crowd and become everyone enemy so i thought i ask for opinions on meta.

Comment: @mehow Flagging is anonymous.  Voting to close is not however.  If you aren't willing to VTC on controversial issues that's perfectly understandable.

Comment: @Servy The OP is <3k.

Comment: @Undo I was answering the question in the general sense, and thus covered both cases.  Hopefully the OP won't be <3k forever, or this question might be read by users on either side of that rep mark.